# Advice for Logic in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to write a redirect script for my website using Javascript and i am having some trouble with the logic. if i do my redirect without setting localStorage counter my site keeps redirecting in a infinite loop so i need to get some logic behind it to stop redirect once it did it once if that makes sense.

here is my code:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('redirect') == null) {
  localStorage.setItem('redirected',0);
};

if (localStorage.getItem('redirect') != "0") {
  $.getJSON("//geoip.nekudo.com/api?callback=",function(data) {
    if( data.country.code == 'AU' ) {};
    localStorage.setItem('redirected',parseInt(localStorage.setItem('redirected') + 1));
  });
  if (localStorage.getItem('redirected') == "1") {};
};
```

Comment: So where do you redirect to?

Comment: `getJSON()` works **asynchronously**, if you're expecting the last `if` to be executed after the response from `getJSON()` come, move the `if` inside the `getJSON` callback.

Comment: so i have 2 domains http://website.dk and http://website.com when code AU i need to goto http://website.com

Comment: So if the current domain is `website.com` why do you want to redirect to itself? Why would not you check the `current domain` and `domain to redirect to` before you redirect?

Comment: Thats exactly the problem i am having. I have a shopify website where i have multiple domains however they all point back to itself but each one has a different language which makes it difficult.

Comment: i want to redirect based on user country so they see there correct language

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You cannot compare 2 strings?

Comment: The problem exactly is, When the user gets redirected from dk because they are in australia to .com then it keeps looping over itself in the redirect to .com each time.

Comment: So why do you redirect to `.com` if a user is already on a `.com` site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109615/discussion-between-elevant-and-zerkms).